# Freshly installed Win10 VM, says "A hypervisor has been detected". Is it a Microsoft bug or VMware bug?

Tags: vmware, hyper-v

In a Windows 10 22H2 host PC， I install VMware workstation 16.2.3, then install a fresh Win10.22h2 VM.

Curiously to see, the Win10 VM's msinfo32.exe reports that:

- Virtualization-based security = Not enabled
- "A hypervisor has been detected" line is present.

[image: msinfo32 in a VM]

That is weird, aren't they contradictory?

This defeats what [this MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v) page says about "A hypervisor has been detected".

[image]

I mean, on a physical PC, if "Virtualization-based security = **Not enabled**", I always see "A hypervisor has been detected" line is **absent**.

On a physical PC, I see either case A or case B below.

[CASE A] Hyper-V feature is not enabled, e.g. on a freshly installed Win10.

[image: A fresh Win10.22H2 physical PC]

[CASE B] Hyper-V feature is enabled. User has enabled in appwiz.cpl **Hyper-V**, **Virtual machine platform**, and **Hypervisor platform**，and, user has not passed `hypervisorlaunchtype=off` as boot parameter.

[image: A physical PC that has enabled Hyper-V]

Comment: `Virtualization-based security` obviously rely on virtualization, but that does not refer to whether your machine is virtualized, but whether the virtualization capability is available on the machine. Often the answer is false on a VM because nested virtualization is either not supported or not enabled by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That is weird, aren't they contradictory?

No. "Virtualization-based security" is not the same thing as "Virtualization" in general and has nothing to do with general-purpose VMs (or with WSL2 for that matter); it's a [very specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-vbs) Windows feature that *makes use of* virtualization to protect the host OS from itself. It can be enabled or disabled separately from the other features that rely on virtualization.

(And specifically, it makes use of the Windows Hypervisor (the same which powers Hyper-V) – it won't function if some other hypervisor is present.

VBS also won't function if the computer doesn't meet any of the several other requirements listed, e.g. if there is no IOMMU or no TPM2.0, even if Windows Hypervisor is present.)

Comment: Then, do you mean that, the word "hypervisor", *in red underlined "A hypervisor has been detected" from my first figure*, underlyingly refers to the virtual machine jail created by VMware workstation software?

Comment: Yes, VMware counts as a hypervisor. (It's not a HyperV-specific term.) It uses the CPU hardware-virtualization functionality in the same way, so it is detectable in the same generic way as well (there's a CPUID bit that indicates "Currently running under virtualization" to the OS). (For more about CPUID try CoreInfo.exe from MS Sysinternals.)